# lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup when building V8

Tags: visual-studio-2017, v8, embedded-v8

I've spent a whole day on this now and I can't seem to get the `.lib` files to build with VS 2017. I followed the V8 docs here:

https://v8.dev/docs/build

Following the instructions does work, but I end up with a V8 command line program in the `out` directory and `.lib` that do NOT work with Visual Studio 2017.

> fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x1422A

I executed this to try to get the build files for the libraries only:

```
gn gen out/lib --args="v8_static_library=true v8_use_snapshot=true v8_use_external_startup_data=false v8_monolithic=true icu_use_data_file=false is_component_build=false is_debug=false"
```

Then ran this: `ninja -C out/lib`

And this was the final result:

```
ninja: Entering directory `out/lib'
[1632/1645] LINK cctest.exe cctest.exe.pdb
FAILED: cctest.exe cctest.exe.pdb
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- ../../../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/lld-link.exe /nologo /OUT:./cctest.exe /PDB:./cctest.exe.pdb @./cctest.exe.rsp
lld-link: error: <root>: undefined symbol: mainCRTStartup
[1634/1645] LINK generate-bytecode-expectations.exe generate-bytecode-expectations.exe.pdb
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I think I'm missing something, but I have no idea at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems my first mistake was changing the prompt to `v8\tools\dev\` and working from there.  The "normal" steps I found actually only work properly from the root of the source. I ended up with `v8\tools\dev\out\x64.release` then `ninja -C out/x64.release v8` failed because `v8` was not accepted in this setup for some reason.

The other thing I did wrong was to edit the `args.gn` file directly and save it.  The CORRECT process is to run `gn args out.gn\x64.release` so that after you save AND close the editor, it automatically re-generates/updates the files.  Most likely changing the file has no effect on its own, and you'll get confused because `ninja` won't even see the changes.

The linker error about corrupt files is because `is_clang` is true by default. Setting `is_clang=false` fixes that error. It just works, I have no idea why; just take it and go ... ;)

The correct way, from the root that worked for me is:

```
python tools\dev\v8gen.py x64.release
python tools\dev\v8gen.py ia32.release
python tools\dev\v8gen.py x64.debug
python tools\dev\v8gen.py ia32.debug
```

This will output files that can be compiled in the "v8\out.gn" folder.

**Tip:** Run "python tools\dev\v8gen.py list" to see a list of possible build configurations.

Next I updated the build arguments:

```
gn args out.gn\x64.release
```

Using these:

```
 is_debug = false                      <-(or true for debug builds)
 target_cpu = "x64"
 is_component_build = false
 v8_static_library = true
 use_custom_libcxx = false
 use_custom_libcxx_for_host = false
 v8_use_external_startup_data = false  <-(or true to use the bin startup files)
 is_clang = false
```

And again for the 32-bit version (changing `"x64"` above to `"x86"` of course):

```
gn args out.gn\ia32.release
```

Then repeated all the above for `x64.debug` and `ia32.debug`.

And compiled them:

```
ninja -C out.gn/x64.debug v8
ninja -C out.gn/ia32.debug v8
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release v8
ninja -C out.gn/ia32.release v8
```

Visual Studio 2017 now builds and links my project against them again now (was an old project I resurrected).

Note: Linking against debug versions of V8 libraries may give an error that  `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` does not match. To fix this I simply went to the C++ project settings (`Confiuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocesor Definitions`) and added `;_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` so it matches.